# How to enable Cors for a single Web Api method on self hosted OWIN

Tags: c#, cors, owin, self-hosting

I need to open single Web Api method to be called from another website (AngularJS) and I can't make it work.

I added references to `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` and `System.Web.Http.Cors`

Added this line to `Configuration` method of my OWIN Startup class:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Added `config.EnableCors();` to `ConfigureWebApi` method

Added

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

above my Web Api controller method.

I still get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load {myUrl}. Response to preflight request doesn't
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not 
allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I tried differenct combinations of the above with no luck. I also saw other replies with adding code to `web.config` and `Global.asax`, but I'm on self hosted OWIN and don't have any of those.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you making an Ajax call to the Web Api service and do you need to pass credentials?

Comment: @BigDaddy thanks, your comment helped actually. I did have some windows authentication going on, and I didn't remove it sufficiently enough from this method. Actually `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` is enough and it works now. The returned response is confusing.

Comment: Confusing responses unnecessarily complicate this stuff.  I was thinking my comment might get you pointed in the right direction.